# Matlab: Import a package in a different directory

Tags: matlab

The [Matlab docs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/importing-classes.html) assume that I have to use `import` to include a class from a package that lies in the same directory of the script/function that I am currently running. How do I import from a package that lies in another directory. For example if I have a directory strcuture such as:

```
+pkg1/
    Class1.m
folder1/
    script.m
```

I want to do something like

```
import ../pkg1.Class1
```

from inside `script.m`. Is there any way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` works whenever the recourse is either located in the same directory or was added [to the search path](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/search-path.html).

Once you added the package to the search path you can use import with an unchanged syntax `import pkg1.Class1`

Comment: The other important alternative is if the package is in the *current* working directory (not necessarily where the script is if the script is on the search path).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought earlier but my MATLAB IDE was behaving strangely yesterday .. It works now

Comment: @Daniel, from what I can tell, the path cannot be set within the script that is importing the package. Adding to the path must be done BEFORE calling the script. Can you confirm that this is true? If so, do you know of a workaround that would allow the script to add to the path?

Comment: Can't help you, I am no longer using matlab.